# wpf app integrated with QB using QBsdk12 fails to establish connection on windows 64 bit

Tags: integration, quickbooks

I have a wpf application which is integrating Quick Books using QBsdk12 and runs successfully when the application is ran on Windows 32 bit and even shows a pop up to authorize the application but when the application is ran on Windows 64 bit it fails. No authentication for connection to authorize is shown. Do we have different versions of QBSDk12 for 64 bit or am i missing on something? Please help..
Regards,
Reena

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you build it in Visual Studio as x86

Comment: Thanks alot.. I did that and I was able to.But I have another question. Do I have to have QuickBooks sdk installed on the client machine to establish connection of my application with the QuickBooks desktop?? Please help.